# Combining regex and ranges causes memory issues

Tags: c++, regex, memory, c++20

I wanted to construct a view over all the sub-matches of `regex` in `text`. Here are two ways to define such a view:

```
    char const text[] = "The IP addresses are: 192.168.0.25 and 127.0.0.1";
    std::regex regex{R"((\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}))"};

    auto sub_matches_view = 
        std::ranges::subrange(
            std::cregex_iterator{std::ranges::begin(text), std::ranges::end(text), regex},
            std::cregex_iterator{}
        ) |
        std::views::join;

    auto sub_matches_sv_view = 
        std::ranges::subrange(
            std::cregex_iterator{std::ranges::begin(text), std::ranges::end(text), regex},
            std::cregex_iterator{}
        ) |
        std::views::join |
        std::views::transform([](std::csub_match const& sub_match) -> std::string_view { return {sub_match.first, sub_match.second}; });
```

- `sub_matches_view`'s value type is `std::csub_match`. It is created by first constructing a view of `std::cmatch` objects (via the regex iterator), and since each `std::cmatch` is a range of `std::csub_match` objects, it is flattened with `std::views::join`.
- `sub_matches_sv_view`'s value type is `std::string_view`. It is identical to `sub_matches_view`, except it also wraps each element of `sub_matches_view` in a `std::string_view`.

Here's an usage example of the above ranges:

```
for(auto const& sub_match : sub_matches_view) {
    std::cout << std::string_view{sub_match.first, sub_match.second} << std::endl; // #1
}

for(auto const& sv : sub_matches_sv_view) {
    std::cout << sv << std::endl; // #2
}
```

Loop `#1` works without problems - the printed results are correct. However, **loop `#2` causes heap-use-after-free issues according to the Address Sanitizer.** In fact, just looping over `sub_matches_sv_view` without accessing the elements at all causes this problem too. [Here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/qoTbTYcxG) is the code on Compiler Explorer as well as the output of the Address Sanitizer.

I am out of ideas as to where my mistake is. `text` and `regex` never go out of scope, I don't see any iterators that might be accessed outside of their lifetimes. The `std::csub_match` object holds iterators (`.first`, `.second`) into `text`, so I don't think it needs to remain alive itself after constructing the `std::string_view` in `std::views::transform`.

*I know there are many other ways to iterate over regex matches, but I am specifically interested in what's causing the memory bugs in my program, I don't need work-arounds for this issue.*

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/qoTbTYcxG

Comment: @Barry Thank you very much, I tried multiple times and couldn't get it to compile fast enough (possibly because I used slightly different flags). On my machine, it takes about 30 seconds. I'll edit your link into the question.

Comment: By the way, libc++ didn't have this issue. https://godbolt.org/z/a7M3jd8ef

Comment: Some bug in transform: https://godbolt.org/z/q4P1x5qTb without `transform` it works.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug of `transform_view`, I think the problem is more like in `<regex>`.

Comment: @MarekR It's definitely not a bug in `transform`.

Comment: @Barry note loop I've added to an example which only skips `std::views::transform`. It works ok.

Comment: @MarekR OP had the same loop? You're not adding any information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `std::regex_iterator` and the fact that it stashes.

---

That type basically looks like this:

```cpp
class regex_iterator {
    vector<match> matches;

public:
    auto operator*() const -> vector<match> const& { return matches; }
};
```

What this means, for instance, is that even though this iterator's reference type is `T const&`, if you have two copies of the same iterator, they'll actually give you references into different objects.

Now, `join_view<R>::iterator` basically looks like this:

```cpp
class iterator {
    // the iterator into the range we're joining
    iterator_t<R> outer;

    // an iterator into *outer that we're iterating over
    iterator_t<range_reference_t<R>> inner;
};
```

Which, for `regex_iterator`, roughly looks like this:

```cpp
class iterator {
    // the regex matches
    vector<match> outer;

    // the current match
    match* inner;
};
```

Now, what happens when you copy this iterator? The copy's `inner` still refers to the original's `outer`! These aren't actually independent in the way that you'd expect. Which means that if the original goes out of scope, we have a dangling iterator!

This is what you're seeing here: `transform_view` ends up copying the iterator (as it is certainly allowed to do), and now you have a dangling iterator (libc++'s implementation moves instead, which is why it happens to work [in this case](https://godbolt.org/z/a7M3jd8ef) as [康桓瑋](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11638718) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72201979/combining-regex-and-ranges-causes-memory-issues#comment127568842_72201979)). But we can reproduce the same issue without `transform` as long as we copy the iterator and destroy the original. For instance:

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

int main() {
    std::string_view text = "The IP addresses are: 192.168.0.25 and 127.0.0.1";
    std::regex regex{R"((\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}))"};

    auto a =  std::ranges::subrange(
            std::cregex_iterator(std::ranges::begin(text), std::ranges::end(text), regex),
            std::cregex_iterator{}
        );

    auto b = a | std::views::join;

    std::optional i = b.begin();
    std::cout << std::string_view((*i)->first, (*i)->second) << '\n'; // fine

    auto j = *i;
    i.reset();
    std::cout << std::string_view(j->first, j->second) << '\n'; // boom
}
```

I'm not sure what a solution to this problem would look like, but the cause is the `std::regex_iterator` and not the `views::join` or the `views::transform`.

Comment: The difference between libstdc++ and libc++ seems to be that the former [explicitly-defaults the copy constructor of `regex_iterator`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/05b9868b182bb9ed2013b39a0bc6297354a0db49/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/regex.h#L2753), which makes `regex_iterator` always copy instead of move in libstdc++. The quick fix would be to add `regex_iterator(regex_iterator&&) = default` for it.